# Adjacency Matrix Graph Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, graph, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to implement the following graph using an adjacency matrix:
[image: graph]

The program being written will find the shortest distance from every store to every other store. This is the code being used:

```js
public class AdjacencyMatrix
{       
    public static final int NUM_NODES = 100;
    public static final int INF = 99999;
    public static final int A = 20;
    public static final int B = 18;
    public static final int C = 47;
    public static final int D = 44;
    public static final int E = 53;
    public static final int F = 67;
    public static final int G = 95;
    public static final int H = 93;
    public static final int I = 88;
    public static final int W = 66;
    
    public static boolean even(int num) 
    {
        return num%2==0;
    }

    public static boolean odd(int num) 
    {
        return num%2==1;
    }

    public static void initialize(int [][] adjMat, int N) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j <N; j++)
                adjMat[i][j]=INF;

        for(int x = 0; x<N; x++)
        {
            int row = x/10;
            int column = x%10;

            if (even(row)) {
                if (column!=9)
                    adjMat[x][x+1]=1;
            }
            if (odd(row)) {
                if (column!=0)
                    adjMat[x][x-1]=1;
            }
            if (even(column)){
                if (row!=9)
                    adjMat[x][x+10]=1;
            }
            if (odd(column)) {
                if (row!=0)
                    adjMat[x][x-10]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static int[][] floydWarshall(int[][] adjMat, int N)
    {
     adjMat = new int[N][N];
     initialize(adjMat, N);

        for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k) 
        {
           for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
           {
              for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) 
              {
                 adjMat[i][j] = Math.min(adjMat[i][j], adjMat[i][k] +   adjMat[k][j]);
              }
           }
        }
        
        return adjMat;
    }
    
    public static int[][] arrayCondenser(int[][] adjMat, int N)
    {
     int[] array = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,W};
     adjMat = floydWarshall(adjMat, N);
     
     
     
     
     return adjMat;
    }

    public static void printGrid(int[][] adjMat)
    {
  for (int i=0; i<NUM_NODES; ++i)
  {
     for (int j=0; j<NUM_NODES; ++j)
     {
         if (adjMat[i][j]==INF)
             System.out.printf("%5s", "INF");
         else
             System.out.printf("%5d",adjMat[i][j]);
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int adjMat[][] = new int[NUM_NODES][NUM_NODES];
        adjMat = floydWarshall(adjMat, NUM_NODES);
 
        printGrid(adjMat);
        
        int A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,W;
        
        

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

How do I condense the 100 x 100 array down to a 10 x 10 that contains the all pairs shortest path only for the highlighted nodes in the graph?

Comment: I don't see any statements in your loop of the form `adjMat[x][x-1]=1` and those edges exist in the picture in the odd-numbered rows.

Comment: For odd-numbered columns in odd-numbered rows, you should have a statement of the form `adjMat[x][x-10]=1`, but you only have that happening for odd-numbered columns in even-numbered rows.

Comment: Also, you need to have 100 elements (indexed 0 through 99) in a dimension, whereas you only have 99.

Comment: This graph has very special structure...obviously.  An adjacency matrix is a _terrible_ choice to represent it.  There are 162 edges requiring a matrix of 10,000 elements, so your wasting 98.4% of the matrix.  A much more sensible approach would be a 10x10 matrix of 4-bit elements denoting whether there's an out-edge in the N,E,S, and W directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your Floyd-Warshall implementation to correctly initialize `adjMat` for the diagonal elements of the adjacency matrix, which should have a value 0.  I also changed the `floydWarshall` method to not re-allocate `adjMat`, which has already been allocated in the `main` method. I also removed a duplicate call to `floydWarshall` in your `arrayCondenser` method.  I have also modified the the `arrayCondenser` method to calculate the condensed array, and added a `printCondensedGrid` method to display the condensed array:

```
public class AdjacencyMatrix {
    public static final int NUM_NODES = 100;
    public static final int INF = 99999;
    public static final int A = 20;
    public static final int B = 18;
    public static final int C = 47;
    public static final int D = 44;
    public static final int E = 53;
    public static final int F = 67;
    public static final int G = 95;
    public static final int H = 93;
    public static final int I = 88;
    public static final int W = 66;

    public static boolean even(int num) {
        return num % 2 == 0;
    }

    public static boolean odd(int num) {
        return num % 2 == 1;
    }

    public static void initialize(int[][] adjMat) {
        for (int i = 0; i < adjMat.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < adjMat.length; j++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    adjMat[i][j] = 0;
                } else {
                    adjMat[i][j] = INF;
                }
            }

        for (int x = 0; x < adjMat.length; x++) {
            int row = x / 10;
            int column = x % 10;

            if (even(row)) {
                if (column != 9)
                    adjMat[x][x + 1] = 1;
            }
            if (odd(row)) {
                if (column != 0)
                    adjMat[x][x - 1] = 1;
            }
            if (even(column)) {
                if (row != 9)
                    adjMat[x][x + 10] = 1;
            }
            if (odd(column)) {
                if (row != 0)
                    adjMat[x][x - 10] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void floydWarshall(int[][] adjMat) {
        // commented this out because you are also allocating
        // adjMat in the main method. 
        //adjMat = new int[adjMat.length][adjMat.length];
        initialize(adjMat);

        for (int k = 0; k < adjMat.length; ++k) {
            for (int i = 0; i < adjMat.length; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < adjMat.length; ++j) {
                    adjMat[i][j] = Math.min(adjMat[i][j], adjMat[i][k] + adjMat[k][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        //return adjMat;
    }

    public static int[][] arrayCondenser(int[][] adjMat, int [] array) {
        int[][] condensedArray = new int[array.length][array.length];
        //adjMat = floydWarshall(adjMat, N);

        for (int storeFrom = 0; storeFrom < array.length; storeFrom++) {
            for (int storeTo = 0; storeTo < array.length; storeTo++) {
                condensedArray[storeFrom][storeTo] = adjMat[array[storeFrom]][array[storeTo]];
            }
        }

        return condensedArray;
    }

    public static void printGrid(int[][] adjMat) {
        System.out.println("Adjacency Matrix: ");
        System.out.printf("%5s", " ");
        for (int i = 0; i < adjMat.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%5d", i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%4s+", " ");
        for (int i = 0; i < adjMat.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%5s", "===");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < adjMat.length; ++i) {
            System.out.printf("%4d|", i);

            for (int j = 0; j < adjMat[i].length; ++j) {
                if (adjMat[i][j] == INF)
                    System.out.printf("%5s", "INF");
                else
                    System.out.printf("%5d", adjMat[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void printCondensedGrid(int[][] adjMat, int stores[]) {
        System.out.println("Condensed grid: ");
        System.out.printf("%5s", " ");
        for (int i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%5d", stores[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf("%4s+", " ");
        for (int i = 0; i < adjMat.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%5s", "===");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < adjMat.length; ++i) {
            System.out.printf("%4d|", stores[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < adjMat[i].length; ++j) {
                if (adjMat[i][j] == INF)
                    System.out.printf("%5s", "INF");
                else
                    System.out.printf("%5d", adjMat[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int adjMat[][] = new int[NUM_NODES][NUM_NODES];
        int[] stores = { A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, W };

        floydWarshall(adjMat);

        printGrid(adjMat);
        int condensedArray[][] = arrayCondenser(adjMat, stores);
        printCondensedGrid(condensedArray, stores);

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the initialization below (moved into an `initialize` method) should reflect your picture more accurately.

In even rows, there are edges from every node to the node to its right.  In odd rows, there are edges from every node to the node to its left.  In every even column, there are edges from every node to the node below.  In every odd column, there are edges from every node to the node above.

I've also changed the dimensions of the matrix to reflect the fact that there are 100 nodes, and not 99.

To test the initialization, I have added a test method `testInit`.  This method runs through each node in the graph and checks nodes to the left, right, above and below to see if there are edges to those nodes.  You can inspect the output of the test method and compare to the picture above.

Both `initialize` and `testInit` are called from `main`.

**EDIT**: I have implemented [Gene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161878/gene)'s suggestion of using a 100 X 4 matrix where the 4 numbers represent the N, S, E, W directions, because those are the only directions in which links can exist.  Gene suggested 4 bits, but I've used 4 array locations which uses more space, but I've put the actual adjacent nodes in those locations (if non-zero).

```
public class AdjacencyMatrix
{       
    public static final int NUM_NODES = 100;
    public static final int NUM_DIRECTIONS = 4;
    public static final int NORTH = 0;
    public static final int EAST = 1;
    public static final int SOUTH = 2;
    public static final int WEST = 3;
    public static boolean even(int num) {
        return num%2==0;
    }

    public static boolean odd(int num) {
        return num%2==1;
    }

    public static void initialize(int [][] adjMat, int N, int DIR) {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for(int dir = 0; dir <DIR; dir++)
                adjMat[i][dir]=0;

        for(int x = 0; x<N; x++)
        {
            int row = x/10;
            int column = x%10;

            if (even(row)) {
                if (column!=9)
                    adjMat[x][EAST]=x+1;
            }
            if (odd(row)) {
                if (column!=0)
                    adjMat[x][WEST]=x-1;
            }
            if (even(column)){
                if (row!=9)
                    adjMat[x][SOUTH]=x+10;
            }
            if (odd(column)) {
                if (row!=0)
                    adjMat[x][NORTH]=x-10;
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int adjMat[][] = new int[NUM_NODES][NUM_DIRECTIONS];
        initialize(adjMat, NUM_NODES, NUM_DIRECTIONS);
        testInit(adjMat, NUM_NODES, NUM_DIRECTIONS);            

    }

    private static void testInit(int[][] adjMat, int N, int DIR) {
        for(int fromNode=0; fromNode < N; fromNode++) {
            System.out.print(fromNode + "-->");
            for (int num=0; num<DIR; num++) {
                if (adjMat[fromNode][num]>0) {
                    System.out.print( adjMat[fromNode][num] + ", ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
0-->1, 10, 
1-->2, 
2-->3, 12, 
3-->4, 
4-->5, 14, 
5-->6, 
6-->7, 16, 
7-->8, 
8-->9, 18, 
9-->
10-->20, 
11-->1, 10, 
12-->22, 11, 
13-->3, 12, 
14-->24, 13, 
15-->5, 14, 
16-->26, 15, 
17-->7, 16, 
18-->28, 17, 
19-->9, 18, 
20-->21, 30, 
21-->11, 22, 
22-->23, 32, 
23-->13, 24, 
24-->25, 34, 
25-->15, 26, 
26-->27, 36, 
27-->17, 28, 
28-->29, 38, 
29-->19, 
30-->40, 
31-->21, 30, 
32-->42, 31, 
33-->23, 32, 
34-->44, 33, 
35-->25, 34, 
36-->46, 35, 
37-->27, 36, 
38-->48, 37, 
39-->29, 38, 
40-->41, 50, 
41-->31, 42, 
42-->43, 52, 
43-->33, 44, 
44-->45, 54, 
45-->35, 46, 
46-->47, 56, 
47-->37, 48, 
48-->49, 58, 
49-->39, 
50-->60, 
51-->41, 50, 
52-->62, 51, 
53-->43, 52, 
54-->64, 53, 
55-->45, 54, 
56-->66, 55, 
57-->47, 56, 
58-->68, 57, 
59-->49, 58, 
60-->61, 70, 
61-->51, 62, 
62-->63, 72, 
63-->53, 64, 
64-->65, 74, 
65-->55, 66, 
66-->67, 76, 
67-->57, 68, 
68-->69, 78, 
69-->59, 
70-->80, 
71-->61, 70, 
72-->82, 71, 
73-->63, 72, 
74-->84, 73, 
75-->65, 74, 
76-->86, 75, 
77-->67, 76, 
78-->88, 77, 
79-->69, 78, 
80-->81, 90, 
81-->71, 82, 
82-->83, 92, 
83-->73, 84, 
84-->85, 94, 
85-->75, 86, 
86-->87, 96, 
87-->77, 88, 
88-->89, 98, 
89-->79, 
90-->
91-->81, 90, 
92-->91, 
93-->83, 92, 
94-->93, 
95-->85, 94, 
96-->95, 
97-->87, 96, 
98-->97, 
99-->89, 98,
```

If you want to keep your original indexing, you can modify the if statements in the `initialize` method like so:

```
        if (even(row)) {
            if (column!=9)
                adjMat[x][x+1]=1;
        }
        if (odd(row)) {
            if (column!=0)
                adjMat[x][x-1]=1;
        }
        if (even(column)){
            if (row!=9)
                adjMat[x][x+10]=1;
        }
        if (odd(column)) {
            if (row!=0)
                adjMat[x][x-10]=1;
        }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137361/discussion-on-answer-by-david-choweller-adjacency-matrix-graph-implementation).